# Create infinite list with Fibonacci numbers

Tags: list, haskell, lazy-evaluation, fibonacci, infinite

I make my next homework =)
My task is to create infinite list with fibonacci numbers [0,1,1,2,3,5,8..]
I can use any function from Prelude.

My try:

```
fibs2 :: [Integer]
fibs2 = reverse $ foldr f [1,0] [0..]
  where 
        f _ (x:y:xs) = (x+y):x:y:xs
```

this function works only with finite lists like [0..100]
with infinite list it gives:

```
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

what i do wrong? how to make "lazy" function?

**UPDATE** 
my second try:

```
fibs4 = 0:[ b | (a, b) <- scanl (\(x,y) _ -> (y,x + y)) (0,1) [0..] ]
```

it works right. :) 
it's normal or strange?

Comment: Think about it: How do you reverse an infinite list? What should the first element be? You need a different approach.

Comment: i update post with 2nd try with scanl function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`foldr` (with a strict combining function) deconstructs an argument list to its very end, and then recombines it through the user-supplied combining function `f`:

```
foldr f z [a,b,c,...,y] = f a (f b (f c (.....(f y z).....)))
```

in your case,

```
fibs2 = reverse $ foldr (\_ (x:y:xs) -> (x+y):x:y:xs) [1,0] [0..]
```

`foldr` here never produces any output. But it's not for the lack of trying: it works very hard recursing down the infinite list in search of its end, because its combining function is *strict* (it matches the rest of `foldr`'s output with `(x:y:xs)` before constructing its own result).

`Foldr` with a strict  combining function expresses recursion, and recursion must have its base case, to stop. What you had in mind is the following:

```
fibs2 = reverse $ snd $ until (null.fst) 
         (\(_t:ts, x:y:xs) -> (ts, (x+y):x:y:xs)) ([0..],[1,0])
```

which is manifestly non-terminating. `ts` just expresses the passing moments of time. We can try to see the whole history of its execution, re-writing it as

```
fibs2 = reverse $ snd $ last $ iterate
         (\(_t:ts, x:y:xs) -> (ts, (x+y):x:y:xs)) ([0..],[1,0])
```

Of course there's no last element in the infinite list. But we can at least see all the interim results now:

```
> mapM_ (print.reverse.snd) $ take 11 $ iterate 
          (\(_:ts, x:y:xs) -> (ts, (x+y):x:y:xs)) ([0..],[1,0])
[0,1]
[0,1,1]
[0,1,1,2]
[0,1,1,2,3]
[0,1,1,2,3,5]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55]
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

So instead of waiting until the very last list is built (which will be *never*) and *then* reversing it, why not produce its elements as we go? It's all there already, anyway. And the last element of each interim result, reversed - isn't it just its first element?

```
> take 11 $ map (head.snd) $ iterate 
          (\(_:ts, x:y:xs) -> (ts, (x+y):x:y:xs)) ([0..],[1,0])
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

Neat, huh. So do we need our explicit time counter, really? Do we need to drag along the whole tail of the previous interim result, or do we just need its first two elements?

```
fibs = map (head.tail) $ iterate (\[x,y] -> [x+y,x]) [1,0]
```

Using tuples for constant length lists will be a bit cleaner. So you see that we've arrived here at one of the canonical definitions,

```
fibs = g (1,0)  where  g (a,b) = b : g (a+b,a)
```

(see also [What's the difference between recursion and corecursion?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144274/whats-the-difference-between-recursion-and-corecursion/196827#196827)).

---

your "second try",

```
fibs4 = 0:[ b | (a, b) <- scanl (\(x,y) _ -> (y,x + y)) (0,1) [0..] ]
```

is actually very close to the above as you can see. `scanl` over the time-counting list is just equivalent to `iterate`. So it's equivalent to

```
fibs4a = [a | (a,b) <- iterate (\(a,b) -> (b, a+b)) (0,1)]
```

which we've seen in the derivation above as a `map` variant, with tuples used instead of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you can't reverse an infinite array.

Have a look at this:

```
0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...
  0,1,1,2,3,5,8, 13...   +
----------------------
0,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,...
```

As you can see from my attempt at showing the relationship how the Fibonacci sequence can be generated using itself, it is quite easy! You would `zipWith` fibonacci with its tails using the addition function!

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
```

For a little bit more detail, here is an expansion of the above.

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) 0:1:? 1:?
fibs = 0 : 1 : (0+1) : zipWith (+) 1:? ?
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) 1:1:? 1:?
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : zipWith (+) 1:2:? 2:?
fibs = 0 : 1 : 1 : 2 : 3 : zipWith (+) 2:3:? 3:?
```

ad infinitum... The `?` represents a `thunk`, a yet unevaluated piece of Haskell computation.

Comment: wow! cool trick =) you make it by yourself or saw somewhere? algorithm is so simple but i can't write working infinite list.

Comment: Hi! I wrote a nice article about such things on my blog, here you go!  http://rafal.io/posts/self-referential-dss.html  Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: to get the full and precise picture, the interim thunks must be named. BTW there's a [documentation entry](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/251/getting-started-with-haskell-language/12240/fibonacci-using-lazy-evaluation#t=201706100714301912677) now, discussing this, @СергейКузминский.